# Query para encontrar se valor está entre "1|3"

Tags: mysql, select

Tenho uma tabela unidades que representa o numero de dormitorios dos predios:

```
id|  dorm
1 |   1|3
```

Nesse caso acima quer dizer que o predio id 1 tem unidades com 1 ou 3 dormitorios.

Aí eu tenho uma busca usando `$_GET` onde o campo do dormitorio é dorm=2, por exemplo

Nesse exemplo preciso que a consulta traga esse id 1, porque a pessoa selecionou mínimo 2 dormitorios, e como na coluna dorm tem 1|3 (que quer dizer que tem unidades de 1 ou de 3 dormitorios) ele deve trazer o id 1.

Para fazer a consulta eu teria que "quebrar" a coluna dorm, isso? Não sei como

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a função [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substring_index.asp) separando os valores e comparando com o valor recebido no GET.

O terceiro parâmetro *positivo* irá retornar o valor à **esquerda** do delimitador `|`, e negativo irá retornar o valor à **direita** do delimitador:

```
"SELECT id FROM tabela
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(dorm,'|',1) >= '$dorm'
OR
SUBSTRING_INDEX(dorm,'|',-1) >= '$dorm'"
```

Se um **ou** outro valor for igual ou maior que o valor do GET, irá retornar o registro.

Comment: só coloquei () no where, pq tenho uns outros ANDs na consulta

Comment: tem um problema nesse, se o dormitorio tiver mais que 1 caracter, ele dá erro, pq corta na metade

Comment: Mostra um exemplo pra eu ver

Comment: ex, id1 = dorm 1|3. id2 = 10|8, id3 = 1|10.

Comment: Leandro, atualizei a resposta... agora faça um teste para ver porque talvez o valor `$dorm` tenha que ficar foras das aspas....

Comment: deu certo sim, aí tentei aplicar esse mesmo para um outro, mas não deu, esse outro tem 4 valores: 20|35|115|10. sabe como posso fazer para esse caso?

Comment: consegui, joguei um dentro do outro SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(metragem,'|',2),'|', -1)